# How to connect Hyperion to sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, hyperion

I have a pivot table that I would like to create a script to export the pivot to the web. I have a web directory that I am able to save to via excel. The format is slightly different than a standard export to a file directory:

this example works when saving to local directory:

`filename = "c:\\temp\\test.xls"`

`ActiveDocument.Sections["Results2"].Export(fil ename,bqExportFormatExcel5,false)`

When trying to export to the web, the following example does not work:

`filename = "http://test/sites/IRTest/test.xls"`

`ActiveDocument.Sections["Results2"].Export(fil ename,bqExportFormatExcel5,false)`

I cannot find a helpful answer anywhere about this topic. If anyone knows how to get this to work that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can directly write to an http server (web) as you are trying do.  If this target destination is inside your firewall, you can map the drive and save the file to the mapped drive/directory.